Получение почтового индекса geopy
  place = address
  location2 = geoLoc2.geocode(place)
  # traverse the data
  data2 = location2.raw
  loc_data = data2["display_name"].split()
  index=loc_data[-2]

Мне нужно получить из текстового адреса либо широты/долготы индекс адреса, но когда я пишу вышеуказанный код, то выводится много ошибок, в основном насчет display_name. Как можно получить индекс из данного адреса с переменной address?(например, address = 'Москва, 620000, Советская 13')
